# How to use Service Account to execute a API call through Cloud composer dag

Tags: rest, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-iam

I have a Dataflow application code which reads data from Bigquery and writes to GCS bucket and some other processing. I am successfully able to run this code from Dataflow UI using Dataflow worker service account which has been granted necessary IAM roles to be able to access BigQuery and GCS. Now i want to run this code through an api call and this api call should be done from a cloud composer dag using PythonOperator such that i can schedule this job to run at some frequency.

When i execute the dag, i get an error that user doesn't has Dataflow developer role assigned to it to be able to create a dataflow job. I want to understand what is the correct approach to be able to run an application from composer.

Is this below approach correct

###Should i create a new Service account which is able to run composer dag and also able to create and then run Dataflow job. This Service account should also have necessary IAM roles to be able to access Bigquery and GCS###
###Also i want to know , i dont want to pass Json key file in the code for authentication. What is the best approach to be able to authenticate a Service Account###

I tried running the composer dag and it failed with authentication error

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of services required by Cloud Composer:
https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/enabling-service#required-services